# Share compiled module reference across test cases

Tags: node.js, jestjs, nestjs

I have got a standard unit test for nestjs application

```
// test.spec.ts

describe('test case', () => {

  beforeAll(async () => {
    module = await createTestingModule();
  });
});

// testSetup.ts

export async function createTestingModule() {
  return Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
  }).compile();
}
```

But `Test.createTestingModule` is called in every test case which takes some time. Can I somehow save the reference to the compiled module and reuse it in other tests?

- first test runs `createTestingModule`, compiles the module and save the reference
- next tests runs `createTestingModule`, but instead of compiling it they will use reference

Script I use to run tests
`jest --setupFiles dotenv/config --coverage --runInBand --detectOpenHandles --forceExit --logHeapUsage`

I was trying to store it in `process` object but i think its not possible this way.

Comment: I think you can use closure and IIFE for that in `testSetup.ts`